# exo_player_control_view overlaps buffering (Progress Bar)

Tags: controller, exoplayer, buffering

I have a custom `exo_player_control_view` where in the top layout I added *80%* black color.

When controls showing, **buffering** from white becomes darker.

How to keep the **buffering** totally white and don't get overlapped by controller.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

Just added View (exo_controller_placeholder) before progressBar.